# JSON parse error: null; nested exception is com.alibaba.fastjson.JSONException

Tags: java, spring-boot

To convert null string to "", FastJsonHttpMessageConverter is introduced. 
The controller defined is:
[image]

The request model difined is:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WebWq.png).
And the configuration of FastJsonHttpMessageConverter is：[configuration of FastjsonHttpMessageConvert](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EMCvc.png)
When I invoke the controller with request body like：[request body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XStrr.png).

Response is: Bad Request: JSON parse error: null; nested exception is com.alibaba.fastjson.JSONException.

I do not know how to solve it and wish any useful help!
Thanks a lot!

Comment: do not links to pic. please paste the code instead

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and with that improve your question. Don't post code/errors/config as images, or off-site resources, the question should be clear from the start, not require clicking 3 links to get an overview.

Answer (score 0):

i suggest to use mapstruct as mapper, here is an example:

1) Adding dependencies and plugin to your pom : 
   -> plugin :

```
<plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>1.3.0.Final</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                    <compilerArgs>
                        <compilerArg>
                            -Amapstruct.defaultComponentModel=spring
                        </compilerArg>
                    </compilerArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.bsc.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-processor-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <defaultOutputDirectory>
                        ${project.build.directory}/generated-sources
                    </defaultOutputDirectory>
                    <processors>
                        <processor>org.mapstruct.ap.MappingProcessor</processor>
                    </processors>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>process</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>process</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                        <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                        <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
```

---> Dependencies :

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
        <artifactId>mapstruct-jdk8</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

---> Pojo example :

```
public class TestPojo{
   private String test1;
   private String test2;
    //getter and setter ....

}
```

--> create your own generic mapper interface :

```
public interface PojoMapper<D,P>{
     P toPojo(D paramterfromRequest);
   }
```

---> Create an implementation of the generic interface :

```
@Mapper
public interface PojoMapper extends PojoMapper<RequestObject, TestPojo>{

  @Override
  default TestPojo toPojo(RequestObject requestObject){
    if(requestObject == null)
      return null;
    else {
      TestPojo test = new TestPojo();
      requestObject.getStringTarget() == null ? test.settest1("") : test.settest1(requestObject.getStringTarget());
      requestObject.getStringTarget2() == null ? test.settest2("") : test.settest2(requestObject.getStringTarget2());
     return test;
    }
  }
 }
```

hope this could be helpful for your or any one else :)

Comment: Yes，I tried. It seems that object mapper can only convert all type with value 'null' to  "", not only for string. eg: objectMapper.getSerializerProvider().setNullValueSerializer(new JsonSerializer<Object>(){
            @Override
            public void serialize(Object o, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator,SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws IOException {
                jsonGenerator.writeString("");
            }
        }

Comment: i have edited my answer, check it please, hope it can give you any help :D

Comment: How would introducting MapStruct help to read JSON to an object?

Comment: by mapping the applyRequest you passed on parameter, map the object to the pojo by changing the null value on the string references by the "", this way : 
 @Autowired
Pojomapper pojoMapper;

@PostMapping(....)
public void test(ApplyRequest1 applyRequest){
    Pojo pojo = pojoMapper.toPojo(applyRequest);
}